# How to assign Json output to a Key variable

Tags: json, python-3.x, python-2.7

Below is my json output data.

> {'mount_disk': '/data', 'actual_size': '2.5T', 'hostname': 'edge1', 'fsystem': '/dev/sdb', 'used_disk': '486G', 'avail_disk': '1.9T', 'percentage': '21%'} {'mount_disk': '/data', 'actual_size': '2.5T', 'hostname': 'edge4', 'fsystem': '/dev/sdb', 'used_disk': '533G', 'avail_disk': '1.8T', 'percentage': '23%'} {'mount_disk': '/data', 'actual_size': '2.5T', 'hostname': 'edge5', 'fsystem': '/dev/sdb', 'used_disk': '664G', 'avail_disk': '1.7T', 'percentage': '29%'}

I want to assign this entire output to a single key. It should look as

> {'description': {'mount_disk': '/data', 'actual_size': '2.5T', 'hostname': 'edge1', 'fsystem': '/dev/sdb', 'used_disk': '486G', 'avail_disk': '1.9T', 'percentage': '21%'} {'mount_disk': '/data', 'actual_size': '2.5T', 'hostname': 'edge4', 'fsystem': '/dev/sdb', 'used_disk': '533G', 'avail_disk': '1.8T', 'percentage': '23%'} {'mount_disk': '/data', 'actual_size': '2.5T', 'hostname': 'edge5', 'fsystem': '/dev/sdb', 'used_disk': '664G', 'avail_disk': '1.7T', 'percentage': '29%'} }

`description` is a key which should hold entire value. How can I achieve this? I tried in many ways but could not meet the expectation.

Comment: Firstly, your json output isn't a valid json format. Is the output is an array of json or it is in a long string?

Comment: @Feng Hao, it is a string which i read from a file and convert it to json.

Below is the code to convert string to json


json_data = {}
with open("json_content.txt","r") as fp:
    for line in fp.readlines():
        if line != "\n":
            split_data = line.split(':',)
            print(split_data)
            json_data[split_data[0]] = split_data[1].split('\n')[0]

print(json_data)

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
json = {'mount_disk': '/data', 'actual_size': '2.5T', 'hostname': 'edge1', 
        'fsystem': '/dev/sdb', 'used_disk': '486G', 'avail_disk': '1.9T',
        'percentage': '21%'} {'mount_disk': '/data', 'actual_size': '2.5T', 
        'hostname': 'edge4', 'fsystem': '/dev/sdb', 'used_disk': '533G',
        'avail_disk': '1.8T', 'percentage': '23%'} {'mount_disk': '/data', 
        'actual_size': '2.5T', 'hostname': 'edge5', 'fsystem': '/dev/sdb', 
        'used_disk': '664G', 'avail_disk': '1.7T', 'percentage': '29%'}

result = {'description' : json}
```

Output:

```
{'description' : 
    {
     'mount_disk': '/data', 'actual_size': '2.5T', 'hostname': 'edge1', 
     'fsystem': '/dev/sdb', 'used_disk': '486G', 'avail_disk': '1.9T',
     'percentage': '21%'} {'mount_disk': '/data', 'actual_size': '2.5T', 
     'hostname': 'edge4', 'fsystem': '/dev/sdb', 'used_disk': '533G',
     'avail_disk': '1.8T', 'percentage': '23%'} {'mount_disk': '/data', 
     'actual_size': '2.5T', 'hostname': 'edge5', 'fsystem': '/dev/sdb', 
     'used_disk': '664G', 'avail_disk': '1.7T', 'percentage': '29%'
    }
}
```

However, I guess your json output data is not in a valid format.

Answer (score 0):

There is no formating for your code, so it is quite difficult to understand. Based on my guess, there is text file contains json string line by line, so this code may do the job.

```
import json
json_data = {'description': []} 
with open("json_content.txt","r") as fp: 
    for line in fp.readlines(): 
        if line != "\n":
            json_data['description'].append(json.loads(line))
print(json_data)
```

the output will be

```
{'description': [{'mount_disk': '/data', 'actual_size': '2.5T', 'hostname': 'edge1', 'fsystem': '/dev/sdb', 'used_disk': '486G', 'avail_disk': '1.9T', 'percentage': '21%'}, {'mount_disk': '/data', 'actual_size': '2.5T', 'hostname': 'edge4', 'fsystem': '/dev/sdb', 'used_disk': '533G', 'avail_disk': '1.8T', 'percentage': '23%'}, {'mount_disk': '/data', 'actual_size': '2.5T', 'hostname': 'edge5', 'fsystem': '/dev/sdb', 'used_disk': '664G', 'avail_disk': '1.7T', 'percentage': '29%'}]}
```